# sonar-scanner error : IOException: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm using sonarqube-6.7.5 & sonar-scanner-3.2.0.1227. Trying to scan the Java code but I see below error while running scanner. Does it sounds something wrong with my "sonar.projectBaseDir"?

```
18:25:39.986 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.sensor.DefaultSensorStorage
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
        at 
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678            at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:291)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:286)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:264)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:121)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:48)
        at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.issue.ignore.pattern.IssueInclusionPatternInitializer
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
        at             at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
        ... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleSettings
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:64)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
        ... 87 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to write analysis log
        at org.sonar.scanner.report.AnalysisContextReportPublisher.dumpModuleSettings(AnalysisContextReportPublisher.java:144)
    org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:62)
        ... 101 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The parameter is incorrect
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFullyImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels.writeFully(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.Channels$1.write(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedWriter.close(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonar.scanner.report.AnalysisContextReportPublisher.dumpModuleSettings(AnalysisContextReportPublisher.java:143)
```

Any clues please?

Comment: Sorry for formatting issue above.

Comment: Can update your question with the debug logs. You can add -X to your command line to see the debug logs. It will be helpful.